# Getting hk2 and Jersey to inject classes

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, hk2

How can I get Jersey to inject classes without creating and registering factories on a one-for-one basis?

I have the following config:

```java
public class MyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyConfig() {
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindFactory(FooFactory.class).to(Foo.class);
                bindFactory(BazFactory.class).to(Baz.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

hk2 will now successfully inject Foo and Baz:

```java
// this works; Foo is created by the registered FooFactory and injected
@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getTest(@Context Foo foo) {
    // code
}
```

But that's not my goal. My goal is to inject objects that wrap these classes. There are many and they each consume different combinations of Foo and Baz. Some examples:

```java
public class FooExtender implements WrapperInterface {

    public FooExtender(Foo foo) {
        // code
    }
}

public class FooBazExtender implements WrapperInterface {

    public FooBazExtender(Foo foo, Baz baz) {
        // code
    }
}

public class TestExtender implements WrapperInterface {

    public TestExtender(Foo foo) {
        // code
    }
    // code
}
```

And so on.

The following does not work:

```java
// this does not work
@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getTest(@Context TestExtender test) {
    // code
}
```

I could create a factory for each and register it in my application config class, using the `bindFactory` syntax like I did with Foo and Baz. But that is not a good approach due to the number of objects in question.

I have read much of the hk2 documentation, and tried a variety of approaches. I just don't know enough of how hk2 actually works to come up with the answer, and it seems like a common enough problem that there should be a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using [FastClasspathScanner](https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner) to grab classes from the package(s) I was interested in. Then I called the appropriate bind methods (`bindAsContract` or `bind`) in batches, as mentioned in [Paul Samsotha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331036/9500925) (after also adding the appropriate `@Inject` annotations).

That seemed to be the most expedient method available to emulate autoscanning and avoid having to manually register each class.

It feels like a hack and I'd be surprised if hk2 doesn't have a better method baked in.

Answer (score 3):

Factories are really only needed for more complex initializations. If you don't need this, all you need to do is bind the service

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    // bind service and advertise it as itself in a per lookup scope
    bindAsContract(TestExtender.class);
    // or bind service as a singleton
    bindAsContract(TestExtender.class).in(Singleton.class);
    // or bind the service and advertise as an interface
    bind(TestExtender.class).to(ITestExtender.class);
    // or bind the service and advertise as interface in a scope
    bind(TestExtender.class).to(ITestExtender.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
}
```

You also need to add `@Inject` on the constructors so HK2 knows to inject the `Foo` and `Baz`

```
@Inject
public TestExtender(Foo foo, Baz baz) {}
```

Comment: Edited to add a note about how to add classes in a more automated way. If there's a more hk2-specific approach, I'd appreciate hearing about it.

Comment: Edit rejected, so I created a new answer to contain the final solution.